# MySQL using trigger to insert into several tables parallelly

Tags: mysql, triggers, database-normalization

I am trying to insert large amount of data (500M rows) into MySQL. I put the whole line into a first table and use an insert after trigger. Since this inserts data to 7 different tables (for normalization purposes) I was wondering whether it would be possible to do the 7 inserts at the same time. Presently I am using MySQL 5.1 which does not allow me to create more triggers on the same table. Can you suggest me something how to increase the insert speed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER temptable_tr AFTER INSERT ON temp
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE TR_00 INT;
        DECLARE TR_1G INT;
        DECLARE TR_2G INT;
        DECLARE TR_3G INT;
        DECLARE TR_1S INT;
        DECLARE TR_2S INT;
        DECLARE TR_3S INT;     
        /* This part repeats 7 times, instead of 00, we can put 1G, 2G, 3G, 1S, 2S, 3S
         Since these 7 parts insert into seven independent tables, would it possible to run them parallely?*/
        BEGIN
            DECLARE T_MD5_00 CHAR(32);
            DECLARE SBN_00 INT;
            DECLARE S_MD5_00 CHAR(32);
            DECLARE SBS_MD5_00 VARCHAR(500);

            SET T_MD5_00 = SELECT MD5(NEW.tr_00) FROM DUAL;
            SET TR_00 = (SELECT tr_00_id FROM trans_00 WHERE trans_00_MD5 = T_MD5_00);
            SET SGN_00 = REPLACE( substring(NEW.tr_00,1,((select LOCATE('>', NEW.tr_00)-1)))  ,'[*:1]','[*]') ;
            SET S_MD5_00 = SELECT MD5(SGN_00) FROM DUAL;
            SET SBN_00 = (SELECT subs_00_id FROM substr_00 WHERE subs_00_MD5 = S_MD5_00);

            IF (TR_00 IS NULL OR SBN_00 IS NULL) THEN
                IF (TR_00 IS NULL) THEN
                    INSERT INTO trans_00(transform_00) values(NEW.tr_00);
                    INSERT INTO trans_00(trans_00_MD5) values(T_MD5_00);
                    SET TR_00 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
                END IF;
                IF (SBN_00 IS NULL) THEN
                    INSERT INTO substr_00(substruct00,subs_00_MD5) values(SGN_00,S_MD5_00);
                    SET SBN_00 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
                END IF;
                INSERT INTO tr_subs_00(tr_00_id,subs_00_id) VALUES(TR_00,SBN_00);
            END IF;
        END;
        .....
        /* At the end collect the TR_?? ids and insert them into an other table:*/
        INSERT INTO pairs(tr_00_id,tr_1G_id,tr_2G_id,tr_3G_id,tr_1S_id,tr_2S_id,tr_3S_id) VALUES(TR_00,TR_1G,TR_2G,TR_3G,TR_1S,TR_2S,TR_3S
    END;
```

Comment: Are you processing one row at a time?

Comment: Yes, I am. The insert is a batch insert. But the trigger processes one row at a time. Do you have any suggestions how to do it in a better way?

Comment: Process the data in "temp" as a set (or as seven sets) rather than one row at a time. Upgrade mySQL, hardware, or both. Consider [asynchronous methods](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/synchronous-vs-asynchronous-execution.html).

Comment: I installed MySQL8.0, dropped the indexes, I switched to InnoDB, because in the newer version this was suggested, I created 7 triggers, optimized the database performance, and instead of uploading 20 000 rows in 34 secs (MyISAM, MySQL 5.4) I have 166secs (InnoDB, MySQL 8.0). I will try to switch back to MyISAM. If does not work, I ran out of ideas. I did not find a way to use asynchronous methods with SQLAlchemy without installing new non-standard packages.

Comment: And just to mention the triggers do not run in parallel. I have a CPU usage between 100-180% and this was the usage before when I had only one trigger. The 7 after insert triggers all have different input and output tables.

Answer (score -1):

Oracle has "INSERT ALL". Doesn't MySQL have it too?
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_rows.php